# UPnP GetAllowedValues() of ScheduledRecording

Tags: java, xml, upnp, http-error

Hello and good evening,

i try to make a request to my UPnP-device, but the result always is:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
CONTENT-LENGTH: 497
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml;charset="utf-8"
CONNECTION: close

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>UPnPError</faultstring>
        <detail>
          <UPnPError xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:control-1-0">
            <errorCode>501</errorCode>
            <errorDescription>Action Failed</errorDescription>
          </UPnPError>
       </detail>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

My request is:

```
POST /Server0/SRS_control HTTP/1.1
HOST: 192.168.2.25:60606
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ScheduledRecording:1#GetAllowedValues"
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
connection: close
Content-Length: 380

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
 <s:Body>
   <u:GetAllowedValues xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ScheduledRecording:1">
     <DataTypeID>A_ARG_TYPE_RecordScheduleParts</DataTypeID>
     <Filter>*:*</Filter>
   </u:GetAllowedValues>
 </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I want to get the allowed values of the quality/resolution field to create a new scheduledRecord. I know just one: "MVGA" but this is just 640x360.
Thank you very much!

Comment: 501 means that current service state prevents the action from succeeding.  Since the scheduled recording spec says the list is static and does not depend on service state,  this sounds like a bug in the service...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But this is a device of a known manufacturer and this would be very bad... :-( Do you know, for example of values for resolution of UPnP-Devices? I've never heard of MVGA, but this is the value it accepts. The video has the resolution of 640x360 then.

Comment: Well known manufacturers have unfortunately shipped massively buggy UPnP media devices... But I'm really not an expert on ScheduledRecording so I can't say for sure what the deal here is. Quickly looking at the spec, the desiredRecordQuality seems to be totally vendor specific -- there are some examples but they are "hypothetical examples": "AUTO" is the only required value.